# Comment System - On a Concatenation

Tags: jquery, concatenation

I have concatenated list of posts, whereby a user can comment on each one (and the comment gets a live update via jquery).  I decided that since I'm using a unique variable for each post, I could just tack that onto the end of the id of the update div, and also tack it onto the end of the class of the submit button, like so:

```
$my_list .= '
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <textarea class="commentbox" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_id"  id="post_id" value=' . $post_id . ' />
        <input type="hidden" name="member_id" id="member_id" value=' . $id . ' />
        <input type="submit" class="submit' . $post_id . '" value="Comment " />
    </form>
    ' . $comment_list . ' // existing comments queried from the db
    <ol id="update' . $post_id . '"></ol> // jquery-ed live update comments
';
?>
```

Everything with respect to the above looks fine (i.e. each submit button gets a unique class and each update div gets a unique id).

So the problem I'm running into now is: how do I get my js function to recognize each of the unique "submits"?  This is what I have now (below). But whenever I click on a submit button next to a post, nothing happens, my page just reloads and a "#" gets added to the end of the url.  I checked my live http headers, and it looks like the comment is getting posted along with the correct unique $post_id... but I believe it's stopping at the js function.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".submit<?php echo $post_id; ?>").click(function() {
        var post_id = $("#post_id").val();  // this is the unique id for each story, in a hidden input
        var member_id = $("#member_id").val();  // this is a member for the commenter, in a hidden input
        var comment = $("#comment").val();  // this is the comment from the input box
        var dataString = 'post_id='+ post_id + '&member_id=' + member_id + '&comment=' + comment;   
        if(comment=='') {
            alert('Please enter a valid comment');
        } else {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "commentajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#update<?php echo $post_id; ?>").append(html);
                    $("#update<?php echo $post_id; ?> li:last").fadeIn("slow");
                    document.getElementById('post_id').value='';
                    document.getElementById('member_id').value='';
                    document.getElementById('comment').value='';
                    $("#comment").focus();
                    $("#flash").hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Just asking, You have a list of posts and each of them has a seperate function like this!

Comment: Yes it is a list of posts... but there is only one function which is in the <head> of the html.

Comment: Why I asked that because your selector `$(".submit<?php echo $post_id; ?>")` has a 'post id' , I just thought you are going to write this kind of functions to every post on the page! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `<input type="submit" class="submit' . $post_id . '" value="Comment " />` with `<input type="button" class="submit' . $post_id . '" value="Comment " />` , I think `return false` will not stop the form submitting here! But could not test this!

Comment: I tried what you said, but not nothing happens, the page submit does not even post.

Comment: Should I include an onclick="newPost() function within the input box?

Comment: You are not using he functionality of a form here, You use AJAX instead, right? Then just remove the form and use a div for that.